Single Ended Signal Filtering/Not filtering
I have a 0-2V 100MHz single-ended square wave signal that is coming to my circuit through a coaxial cable. I want to convert this single-ended signal to differential and route it on the PCB in this way. My question is: Should I filter this SE signal when it enters the circuit? Or should I use it directly without filtering? I would appreciate comments from friends with practical experience on this matter.
Update!! You're right to ask for more details about the application. I want to read and compare pulses with widths ranging from 5ns to 20ns across 3 different channels. I will compare their rising edges. Which signal arrives fist and the delay between rising edges. My plan is as follows: I will first convert the SE signals coming from the SMA connectors into differential signals. I will route these differential signals on the circuit and read them with the FPGA. The analog front end I use for this purpose must have minimal propagation delay, and it must remain consistent.

It's a typical "depends" questions I guess, so voting to close. What must your signal comply with? Does your balun satisfy this already? What is potentially present in the signal that might be of harm?

People with experience in this matter need to know what you want to do with the signal once it's on the board. If it's to clock something, then those nice square edges of the square wave might be useful, and no filtering should be used at all. If you want to use it as a sinewave, then it must be filtered.

See updated version. I hope it will help you to understand what i am planning to do

How much distance do the signals have to travel, can they not be arranged to route directly (shortest path) to the receiver/analyzer (FPGA, I'm guessing?)? || What is the bandwidth of the signal, can it be AC-coupled for example? (Being 0-2V "square" implies a DC baseline, but maybe this can be discarded.) How about EMI (interference) or transient immunity requirements, if any?

Hi @TimWilliams, You may think max 15cm SMA to FPGA pin. Bandwith is 350Mhz. How will making the signal AC coupled affect the solution? For now there is no EMI -Trnasient requirement.

tobalt mentioned a balun, for which AC coupling would be relevant. Is there something wrong with just reading the signals directly at the FPGA (VCCIO = 1.8-2.5V perhaps, or SSTL using VREF = 1V, or LVDS with pin_N = 1V if CMR adequate)? Can you discuss the route, and what interference (if any) might be picked up that would necessitate differential?
